# PHP/MySQL - Analyzing common sets across multiple sets

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, data-analysis

Let's say I have two tables, `people` and `families`.

`families` has two fields - `id` and `name`. The `name` field contains the family surname.

`people` has three fields - `id`, `family_id` and `name` - The `family_id` is the id of the family that that person belongs to. The  `name` field is that person's first name.

It's basically a one to many relationship with one family having many people.

I want to get a lists of name sets, ordered by the highest occurrence of the largest set of names across families.

That probably doesn't make much sense...

To explain what I want further, we can score each set of names. The 'score' is the array size * number of occurrences across families.

For example, let's say two names, 'John' and 'Jane' both existed in three families - That set's 'score' would be 2*3 = 6.

How could I get an array of sets of names, and the set's 'score', ordered by each set's score?

Sample Result Set (I've put it in a table layout, but this could be a multi-dimensional array in PHP) - Note this is just randomly thought up and doesn't reflect any statistical name data.

```
names              | occurrences | score
Ben, Lucy          | 4           | 8
Jane, John         | 3           | 6
James, Rosie, Jack | 2           | 6
Charlie, Jane      | 2           | 4
```

Just to clarify, I'm not interested in sets where:

- The number of occurrences is 1 (obviously, just one family).
- The set size is 1 (just a common name).

I hope I have explained my somewhat complex problem - if anyone needs clarification please say.

Comment: Does the complete working set fit into RAM ? I.e.: Can I build up the Array completly in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it:

```
<?php
require_once('query.lib.php');

$db=new database(DB_TYPE,DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_MISC);
$qry=new query('set names utf8',$db);

//Base query, this filters out names that are in just one family
$sql='select name, cast(group_concat(family order by family) as char) as famlist, count(*) as num from people group by name having num>0 order by num desc';
$qry=new query($sql,$db);

//$qry->result is something like 
/*
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => cathy
            [1] => george
            [2] => jack
            [3] => john
            [4] => jane
            [5] => winston
            [6] => peter
        )

    [famlist] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2,4,5,6,8
            [1] => 2,3,4,5,8
            [2] => 1,3,5,7,8
            [3] => 1,2,3,6,7
            [4] => 2,4,7,8
            [5] => 1,2,6,8
            [6] => 1,3,6
        )

    [num] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 3
        )

)

$qry->rows=7
*/

//Initialize
$names=$qry->result['name'];
$rows=$qry->rows;
$lists=array();
for ($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++) $lists[$i]=explode(',',$qry->result['famlist'][$i]);

//Walk the list and populate pairs - this filters out pairs, that are specific to only one family
$tuples=array();
for ($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++) {
  for ($j=$i+1;$j<$rows;$j++) {
    $isec=array_intersect($lists[$i],$lists[$j]);
    if (sizeof($isec)>1) {
      //Every tuple consists of the name-list, the family list, the length and the latest used name 
      $tuples[]=array($names[$i].'/'.$names[$j],$isec,2,$j);
    }
  }
}

//Now walk the tuples again rolling forward, until there is nothing left to do
//We do not use a for loop just for style
$i=0;
while ($i<sizeof($tuples)) {
  $tuple=$tuples[$i];
  //Try to combine this tuple with all later names
  for ($j=$tuple[3]+1;$j<$rows;$j++) {
    $isec=array_intersect($tuple[1],$lists[$j]);
    if (sizeof($isec)>0) $tuples[]=array($tuple[0].'/'.$names[$j],$isec,$tuple[2]+1,$j);
  }
  $i++;
}

//We have all the tuples, now we just need to extract the info and prepare to sort - some dirty trick here!
$final=array();
while (sizeof($tuples)>0) {
  $tuple=array_pop($tuples);
  //name list is in $tuple[0]
  $list=$tuple[0];
  //count is sizeof($tuple[1])
  $count=sizeof($tuple[1]);
  //length is in $tuple[2]
  $final[]=$tuple[2]*$count."\t$count\t$list";
}

//Sorting and output is all that is left
rsort($final);
print_r($final);
?>
```

I am sorry I just realized I use a query lib that I can't source in here, but from the comment you will easily be able to create the arrays as in the section "Initialize".

Basically what I do is starting with the pairs I keep an array of the families all the names in the current name list belong to, then intersect it with all not-yet tried names.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
SELECT
    f.name AS 'surname',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.name ORDER BY p.name) AS 'names',
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.name) AS 'distinct_names',
    COUNT(p.id) AS 'occurrences',
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.name) * COUNT(p.id) AS 'score'
FROM
    families f
    LEFT JOIN people p ON ( f.id = p.family_id )
GROUP BY
    f.id
ORDER BY
    f.name
```

Comment: Nope... in my complete data set the top name only occurs 3 times, yet your query says there is a set of 6 names which all occur 6 times in different families!